# Comparing columns based on multi index in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df that has row labels `Colour`, `Clothes` and `Week` and two columns `diff` and `diff_two`.

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['Green', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Black'], ['tshirt', 'jeans', 'pants', 'dress'], ['2017_46']],
           names=['Colour', 'Clothes', 'Week'],
           sortorder=0)
```

What is the easiest way to iterate through rows and compare `diff` and `diff_two` which contain strings?

My idea was to use loop over the dataframe

```
for colour in colour_list:
    for clothes in clothes_list:
        if colour in df.index.level[0] and clothes in df.index.level[1]:
            if df.loc[colour, clothes]['diff'] = df.loc[colour, clothes]['diff2']: do something
```

This is wrong as the if condition is always true, i.e. it doesn't look the index as a tuple, i.e. (colour, clothes).

What would be the best way to compare two columns with multi indices?

Thanks!

Updating question with an example:

```
Colour    Clothes    Week    diff     diff1
Green     Jeans      50      Mango    Zara
Yellow    Shirt      50      Zara     Zara   
Blue      Shirt      50      Prada    nan
Green     Jeans      50      Zara     Zara
Green     Jeans      50      nan      nan
```

Updating with the desired output:

```
Colour    Clothes    Week    diff     diff1    output
Green     Jeans      50      Mango    Zara     Mango --> Zara
Yellow    Shirt      50      Zara     Zara     No difference
Blue      Shirt      50      Prada    nan      Prada --> nan    
Green     Jeans      50      Zara     Zara     No difference
Green     Jeans      50      nan      nan      nan --> nan
```

Comment: Can you create sample of dataframe? 3-4 rows?

Comment: Thank you, what is desired output from sample?